# jQuery adding a numerical value to a span element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML span element as shown below.

```
<span id="total_cost">4.99</span>
```

Then two following input elements as shown below (one radio field and one checkbox).

```
<!-- radio field -->
  <input type="radio" name="delivery_method" value="standard" checked> standard (FREE)
  <input type="radio" name="delivery_method" value="signed"> Signed (2.00)
  <input type="radio" name="delivery_method" value="guaranteed"> Guaranteed (6.22)

<!-- checkbox -->
  <input type="checkbox" value="digital" name="digital"> Digital copy (2.00)
```

On selection I would like what the user pressed for the radio field and checkbox field to be added to the value in the span element `#total_cost`. I would like to use jQuery for this solution.

I have got the radio fields working using javascript but I would like to use jQuery and I also can't get the checkboxes to work as well. Code for javascript shown below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('input[name="delivery_method"]').on('change', function(){
    if ($(this).val()=='signed') {
        $("#delivery_price").html("&pound;2.00");
        $("#delivery_method").html("Royal Mail Signed For First Class");
        $("#total_cost").html("&pound;<?php echo ($item)*4.99 + 2.00; ?>");
    } else if($(this).val()=='guaranteed')  {
        $("#delivery_price").html("&pound;6.22");
        $("#delivery_method").html("Royal Mail Special Delivery Guaranteed by 1PM");
        $("#total_cost").html("&pound;<?php echo ($item)*4.99 + 6.22; ?>");
    } else {
        $("#delivery_price").html("&pound;0.00");
        $("#delivery_method").html("Royal Mail First Class");
        $("#total_cost").html("&pound;<?php echo ($item)*4.99; ?>");
    }
});
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<span id="total_cost">4.99</span>

<!-- radio field -->
<input type="radio" name="delivery_method" value="standard" data-price="0.00" data-method="Royal Mail First Class" checked />standard (FREE)
<input type="radio" name="delivery_method" value="signed" data-price="2.00" data-method="Royal Mail Signed For First Class" />Signed (2.00)
<input type="radio" name="delivery_method" value="guaranteed" data-price="6.22" data-method="Royal Mail Special Delivery Guaranteed by 1PM" />Guaranteed (6.22)
<!-- checkbox -->
<input type="checkbox" value="digital" name="digital" />Digital copy (2.00)
```

then

```
$('input[name="delivery_method"], input[name="digital"]').on('change', function () {
    var $del = $('input[name="delivery_method"]:checked');
    var $dig = $('input[name="digital"]');

    $("#delivery_price").html('&pound;' + $del.data('price'));
    $("#delivery_method").html($del.data('method'));

    var price = (parseFloat($del.data('price')) || 0) + ($dig.is(':checked') ? 2 : 0);
    $("#total_cost").html('&pound;' + price.toFixed(2));
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/KTV7S/)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show any code for the checkbox, so i am unsure what you have tried or why it is failing or what exactly you are trying to do with it, but if you just need the value of the checkbox

Give the checkbox an ID

```
 <input type="checkbox" ID='digital' value="digital" name="digital"> Digital copy (2.00)
```

here is a sample [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2NJH4/5/)

Answer (score 0):

hope that's will help you: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ItayB/dKXSz/)

```
var item = 0; //<?php echo ($item) ?>;

$('input[name="delivery_method"]').on('change', function(){
    var total = 0;
    if ($(this).val()=='signed') {
        $("#delivery_price").html("&pound;2.00");
        $("#delivery_method").html("Royal Mail Signed For First Class");
        total = item * 4.99 + 2.00;
        $("#total_cost").text(total);
    } else if($(this).val()=='guaranteed')  {
        $("#delivery_price").html("&pound;6.22");
        $("#delivery_method").html("Royal Mail Special Delivery Guaranteed by 1PM");
        total = item * 4.99 + 6.22;
        $("#total_cost").html(total);
    } else {
        $("#delivery_price").html("&pound;0.00");
        $("#delivery_method").html("Royal Mail First Class");
        total = item * 4.99;
        $("#total_cost").html(total);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This works but the value needs to be added to the original 4.99 and not reset it. How would that be possible?